# Change the colors of the google maps

Tags: google-maps

is it possible with the new Google maps javascript API to change the colors of the maps to have something like this [map under the light blue panel](http://www.flickr.com/photos/31753593@N05/5576350261/sizes/l/in/photostream/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Styled maps might be what you are looking for,

It's worth mentioning the wizard first (note that in #9, it should be `styles`, not `style`)

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com

These are references:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StyledMapType

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html

There's an example of a styled map in the static API
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#StyledMaps

The saturation and lightness control the look. Less saturated = less color, more lightness = whiter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var grayStyles = [
        {
          featureType: "all",
          stylers: [
            { saturation: -90 },
            { lightness: 50 }
          ]
        },
      ];
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.325663, 19.8029607),
        zoom: 15,
        styles: grayStyles,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1125516 if you like the answer, you should 'accept' it. Click the hollow tick just under the voting buttons for the answer.

Comment: Where do we add the Google Maps API key in the code above please?

Comment: @Steve Back when I wrote the example above the key was optional, and I think it still is for light usage. Please read the official docs, I don't really work with Google maps anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it would be to embed the map and then overlay it with a semi-transparent image. It wouldn't change the colours to grey-scale, but you can fade it out quite a bit. Then position all content over it with a much higher z-index.

This is not advisable though as it was cause page load times to shoot through the roof!