# Changing colors on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, colors

I have already looked at a number of tutorials on Stack Overflow about how to change the colors on Google Maps, and none of them have worked for me. I just would like the map to be tinted a blue color.

Here is the Javascript I'm using for my map. The map has additional code work so that it will give directions to the users (not sure if that is somehow interfering).

Also, as dumb as this sounds, I'm unsure if I'm using the new version of Google maps. The map is being called somehow in the javascript, but I don't know where, and I'm a little confused how you know you're using the new version of google maps.

Please help!

```
(function () {
function Map(address, desc, title, markerico, spanId) {




var me = this;

this.spanId = spanId;

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

var blue = {
        stylers: [
        { saturation: 60 },
        { lightness: 20 },
        { hue: '#0000BB'}
    ]

 };


var myOptions = {
    styles: blue,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: latlng


};



this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-" + this.spanId), myOptions);
this.contentString = (desc);
this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

this.directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("route-" + this.spanId));
this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: city,
    map: this.map,
    title: title,
    icon: markerico,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});



var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: this.contentString
});

google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.open(me.map, me.marker);
});

this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var city = address;

this.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': city }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        address = results[0].formatted_address;

        me.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        me.marker.setOptions({
        position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});

if (document.getElementById('start-' + this.spanId)) {
    var input = document.getElementById('start-' + this.spanId);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

        input.className = '';
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            input.className = 'notfound';
            return;
        }   
    }); 
}


    };

    Map.prototype.route = function() {
    var me = this;
    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("travel-" + this.spanId);
    for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
        if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
        var selectedMode = radioButtons[i].value;
        }
    };
    var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById('start-' + this.spanId).value,
        destination: document.getElementById('end-' + this.spanId).value,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
    };

    me.directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        } else if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
        alert("No corresponding geographic location could be found for the specified address. This may be due to a recent address, or incorrect.");
        }
    });
};

Map.prototype.error = function (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
    case e.TIMEOUT:
        alert('Timeout');
        break;
    case e.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        alert('Position unavailable');
        break;
    case e.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        alert('Permission denied.');
        break;
    case e.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        alert('Unknown error');
        break;
    }
};

Map.prototype.geocode = function (l) {
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(l.lat, l.lng);
    var me = this;
    me.geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latLng
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
        document.getElementById('start-' + me.spanId).value = results[0].formatted_address;
        } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
};

Map.prototype.initiate_geolocation = function() {
var me = this;
console.log(this, this.spanId);
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // HTML5 GeoLocation
    function getLocation(position) {
    me.geocode({
        "lat": position.coords.latitude,
        "lng": position.coords.longitude
    });
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, this.error);
} else if(typeof google == 'object') { // Google AJAX API fallback GeoLocation
    if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
    this.geocode({
        "lat": google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude,
        "lng": google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude
    });
    }
}
};

function createMaps() {
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    var span = spans[i];

    if (span.className != 'mapgen')
        continue ;

    var spanId = span.id;

    var organisation = span.getAttribute('data-org');
    var phone        = span.getAttribute('data-phone');
    var url          = span.getAttribute('data-url');
    var fax        = span.getAttribute('data-fax');
    var title        = span.getAttribute('data-title');
    var desc         = span.getAttribute('data-desc');
    var street       = span.getAttribute('data-street');
    var city         = span.getAttribute('data-city');
     var state         = span.getAttribute('data-state');
    var zip         = span.getAttribute('data-zip');
    var country      = span.getAttribute('data-country');
    var image        = span.getAttribute('data-image');
    var markerico    = span.getAttribute('data-marker');
    var mode         = span.getAttribute('data-mode');
    var address      = '' + street + ',' + city + ',' + country + '.';
    var orgid        = organisation.replace(/ /g, "-");

    if ( mode == "only") {
            var htmlmap = '<div class="form-gmaps clearfix" id="form-gmaps-'+spanId+'" >'
        +'<input class="end hidden" id="end-'+spanId+'" name="to" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Los Angeles" />'
        +'    <div class="contentmap" id="contentmap-'+spanId+'" >'
        +'        <div class="map" id="map-'+spanId+'" ></div> '
        +'    </div> '
        +'</div>';

        document.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML += htmlmap;

    } else if (mode == "itinerary") {
        var htmlmap = '<div class="form-gmaps clearfix" id="form-gmaps-'+spanId+'" >'
        +'<form style="display:block;" id="geoloc-'+spanId+'" name="geoloc" action="" method="post">'
        +'  <table class="iti" border="0" width="696">'
        +'      <tbody>'
        +'          <tr valign="top">'
        +'              <td align="right" class="o">'
        +'                  <label for="start" class="1-1">Start :</label>'
        +'              </td>'
        +'              <td align="left">'
        +'                  <input id="start-'+spanId+'" name="from" class="start n" type="text">'
        +'              </td>'
        +'              <td  class="annoy" align="left" >'
        +'                  <input type="radio" name="travel-'+spanId+'" value="DRIVING" checked="checked"> Driving'
        +'              </td>'
        +'          </tr>'
        +'          <tr>'
        +'              <td align="left"  class="th">'
        +'                  <label for="end">End :</label>'
        +'              </td>'
        +'              <td>'
        +'                  <input class="end" id="end-'+spanId+'" name="to" readonly="readonly" class="n" type="text" value="'+address+'">'
        +'              </td>'
        +'              <td class="f fy" >'
        +'                  <input class="get" id="iti-'+spanId+'" type="button" value="Directions">'
        +'              </td>'
        +'              <td  class="annoy2" align="left" >'
        +'                  <input type="radio" name="travel-'+spanId+'" value="WALKING" > Walking'
        +'              </td>'
        +'          </tr>'
        +'      </tbody>'
        +'  </table>'
        +'</form>'
        +'<div class="contentmap" id="contentmap-'+spanId+'" >'
        +'  <div id="map-'+spanId+'" class="map"></div> '
        +'      <div id="route-'+spanId+'">'
        +'      </div>'
        +'  </div> '
        +'</div>';
        document.getElementById(spanId).innerHTML += htmlmap;

    }

    var desctot = '<div id="hcard-'+orgid+'" class="vcard">'
        +'<div class="org" style=\"font-family:sans-serif;\">'
        +'  <b>'+organisation+'</b>'
        +'</div>'
        +'<hr>'
        +'<span style=\"font-size:12px;line-height:20px;font-family:sans-serif;\">'
        +'  <b>Url : </b>'
        +'      <a class="url fn n" href="'+url+'" title="'+title+'">'+title+'</a>'
        +'  <br />'
        +'  <b>Description : </b>'
        +'      '+desc+'<br />'
        +'  <b style="display:inline-block;">Address : </b>'
        +'  <div class="adr" style="display:inline-block;">'
        +'      <div class="street-address" style="display:inline-block;"> '+street+'</div>, <span class="locality">'+city+'</span>    , <span class="locality">'+state+'</span>    , <span class="locality">'+zip+'</span>    , <span class="country-name">'+country+'</span>.'
        +'  </div>'
        +'  <br />'
        +'  <b>Phone : </b>'
        +'  <div class="tel" style="display:inline-block;">'+phone+'</div>'
        +'  <br />'
        +'  <b>Fax : </b>'
        +'  <div class="tel" style="display:inline-block;">'+fax+'</div>'
        +'  <br />'
        +'  <div class="img-shop">'
        +'      <img src="'+image+'" height="50" width="300">    '
        +'  </div>'
        +'  </span>'
        +'</div>';

    var map = new Map(address, desctot, title, markerico, spanId);

    if (mode == "itinerary") {
        var tmap = map; // Create a copy of map in tmap to use in onclick callback
        document.getElementById('iti-'+spanId+'').onclick = function () { tmap.route() };
        document.getElementById('geo-'+spanId+'').onclick = function () { tmap.initiate_geolocation() };
    }
}
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', createMaps);
}
)();
```

Comment: What were the tutorials you have found? And how are you applying the color?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660178/change-the-colors-of-the-google-maps?rq=1  -- This one is a good example of ones I've been trying. Most of the ones I've found apply the color through the Javascript in "styles".

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-maps-styles/ --Another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `styles` object to your map options:

```
var blue = [
    {
        featureType: "all",
        stylers: [
            { saturation: 60 },
            { lightness: 20 },
            { hue: '#0000BB'}
        ]
    }
];
```

The `hue` will change the color. You have to play around with those parameters until you find the desired blue color.

You can apply the colors to the map options:

```
var mapOptions = {
    styles: blue
}
```

And assign them to your map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-" + this.spanId)), mapOptions);
```

More info to be found on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#stylers

Comment: Still doesn't work for me for some reason. When I added that last bit of coding, the map dissappeared completely, when I tried replacing " this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-" + this.spanId), myOptions);" with "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);" it still disappeared. And without even including the last bit, the map showed up but wasn't blue.

Comment: 'map' in my example referred to an element with the id 'map' you need to change that to your id. But I have updated my answer with the ID you are using. Should work now?

Comment: My map is also using this script : http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true    Does that change anything?

Comment: No that should not change anything. And it looks like version 3 by the way. (Latest one)#

Comment: It's also linked to this: http://www.google.com/jsapi but I'm assuming that doesn't matter either. So weird. Any other ideas why the heck it won't just let me change the color?

Comment: Can you update the code in your question what you have now. Including the styles.

Comment: Got it working!! I forgot to include the "feature all" part. Thanks so much for your help!