# Colour Google Map

Tags: javascript, css, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am modifying a website that uses google map in the *contact us* page. the major colour in the current map is blue, I need to change that in to red. I have tried **CSS** rules by applying background-color property, but it is not affecting the map. I have googled and found **JSON** object is used to colour the map. and I have created a colour combination from a website,and that JSON is given below

```
[{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"weight":"1.06"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#baed7c"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
```

This is the javascript code I found in the website to get map, actually this method is used to point two locations in a same map.

```
var contact = {"lat":"latitude-1", "lon":"longitude-1"}; //Change a map coordinate here!
    var contact2 = {"lat":"latitude-2", "lon":"longitude-2"};


    try {

        var mapContainer = $('.map');
        mapContainer.gmap3({
            infowindow:{
                address:"http://goo.gl/maps/Mt7xc",
                options:{
                    content: "content to display on first location"
                },
                events:{
                    closeclick: function(infowindow){
                        alert("closing : " + infowindow.getContent());
                    }
                }
            },

            action: 'addMarker',
            marker:{
                options:{
                    icon : new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/marker.png')
                }
            },
            latLng: [contact.lat, contact.lon],
            map:{
                center: [contact.lat, contact.lon],
                zoom: 5,
                center:contact
                },
            },
            {action: 'setOptions', args:[{scrollwheel:false}]}
        );

        mapContainer.gmap3({
            infowindow:{
                address:"http://goo.gl/maps/Mt7xc",
                options:{
                    content: "content to display on second location"
                },
                events:{
                    closeclick: function(infowindow){
                        alert("closing : " + infowindow.getContent());
                    }
                }
            },
            action: 'addMarker',
            marker:{
                options:{
                    icon : new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/marker.png')
                }
            },
            latLng: [contact2.lat, contact2.lon],
            map:{
                zoom: 5,
                },
            },
            {action: 'setOptions', args:[{scrollwheel:false}]}
        );

    } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
```

Now I need to join both json variable and the map code, Is that possible ? or do I need to create a new map using Google Map API ? any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you try to have a look at [this example](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-maps-styles/)?

Comment: Or this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660178/change-the-colors-of-the-google-map)?

Comment: @d_z90 the question mentioned you above is not duplicate, both question is in different scenario

Comment: @d_z90 but the example you have given sounds good, let em try that

Comment: Didn't want to say it was a duplicate, just that it can be helpful :)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem, the posted code doesn't look like it will work to me.

Comment: [Maps API v3 Simple styled map](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/zLxafos3/)

Answer (score 1):

I would have commented also but I am still building my rep.

Have you considered a different approach? Using CSS you could simply use hue-rotate and saturate filters on the map iframe to style the main colours to match/contrast/compliment the webpage that it is embedded on, I have made a quick codepen example of how I'd go about that:

```
iframe {
  filter:hue-rotate(160deg) saturate(3) brightness(0.9);
  -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(160deg) saturate(3) brightness(0.9);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbboaW

I hope this helps! Good Luck.

Comment: I have tried using hue rotation but it has only limited colors. Actually I need red color for see area