# Google Map JS API iframe not being populated

Tags: google-maps-api-3

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660208/667903), I've used the following code on [this page](http://divi.insightcomdes.com.au/brand/):

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB6ElZHhJNP-A9LkwwDvVNqvCH_W3kICjk"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var grayStyles = [
    {
        featureType: "all",
        stylers: [
        { saturation: -90 },
        { lightness: 50 }
        ]
    },
    ];
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-31.947414, 115.835933),
    zoom: 15,
    styles: grayStyles,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

(I added our API key)

The output at bottom right of the page above contains:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="z-index: -1; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: none;" src="about:blank">
  #document
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

[image]

There are no console errors.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you relocate your scripts to the bottom of the page and styles to the head. Then add height, width and display block to the div with Id of map_canvas.

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: block; height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Also, best to remove any inline styles.